# Need to use react hooks to display a component based on button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I have multiple components and a list of buttons. When I hit a button, I want to use reacthooks to display the corresponding component in {displayComponent}. I only want one component displaying at a time (so if you hit another button it will replace whatever was there previously).

Can someone tell me where i've gone wrong? This isn't working (it's just displaying all three components and the visibility doesn't change). My idea was to have the component display based on if displayComponent matched it's id.

How can I fix it and is there are more efficient way to accomplish this?

```
      import Component1 from "./components/comp1";
      import Component2 from "./components/comp2";
      import Component3 from "./components/comp3";


  function ComponentSelection() {


    let [displayComponent, setDisplayComponent] = useState(null);


return(
        <Button onClick={setDisplayComponent = "comp1">Click to display component 1</Button>
        <Button onClick={setDisplayComponent = "comp2"}>Click to display component 2</Button>
        <Button onClick={setDisplayComponent = "comp3"}>Click to display component 3</Button>

        {displayComponent}

        <Component1 id='comp1' display={displayComponent === 'comp1'} />
        <Component2 id='comp2' display={displayComponent === 'comp2'} />
        <Component3 id='comp3' display={displayComponent === 'comp3'} />
)
}

export default ComponentSelection
```

Comment: In addition to the answer below, you should always set state to a `const` so that it will break if you ever do this accidentally in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood what hooks are. The second element in the returned array is a function to set it. Try this instead:

```
<Button onClick={() => setDisplayComponent("comp1")}>Click to display component 1</Button>
```

Comment: You are saint. That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please don't forget to the accept the answer and up-vote if it was useful to you.